# Polynomial ring modulo ideal generated by linear factor

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, ring-isomorphism

How do you prove that, for any integer $n$,
$$ℤ[X]/(X-n) ≅ ℤ$$

The following straightforward way seems arduous: write an arbitrary $∑_i a_iX^i ∈ ℤ[X] $ as an integer plus $X - n$. I wouldn't know how to do that.

Smarter is probably to use the First Isomorphism Theorem: find a homomorphism 
$f : ℤ[X] \rightarrow ℤ[X]$ with $\ker f = (X -n)$ and im$f = ℤ$. Is that smarter, though, or is that just a rephrasing of the first problem?

Could this be done in the same manner for all commutative rings, and not just ℤ?

Comment: It is indeed smarter, all the more so as the homomorphism is obvious.

Comment: On the one hand I want to say that it is the homomorphism $f(∑_i a_iX^i) = ∑_i a_iX^i $ "mod $X-1$", but what would that mean exactly in $ℤ[X]$?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman No, it's just the one induced by $X\mapsto n$.

Comment: And it is valid for any commutative ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid for every commutative ring $R$ and linear polynomial $X-r$, and the first isomorphism theorem is a good approach.

But you should use it for a homomorphism $R[X] \to R$.

> $\sum_i a_iX^i\mapsto \sum_i a_ir^i$